# Проблема с дублированием фунции с при каждом вызове функции. Проблема при отладке игры

Tags: javascript, функции, разработка-игр

Спрашиваю в первый раз, так что если что то делаю не так , готов к конструктивной критике. 
Пишу игру, где игроку необходимо нажать кнопки в той последовательности, в которой ему их показывает программа. В случае если игрок ввел все правильно, игра должна начаться с начала и количество элементов увеличится на один. Столкнулся с проблемой что каждый раз когда игра начинается с начала  `$("button").click(function(){.......}` вызывается столько, раз сколько прошло уровней , а не один как необходимо.

В итоге  `console.log("приняли значение с кнопки " + numberOfButten );`
вызывается столько раз сколько прошло уровней.
как мне ограничить или закрыть считыватель кликов  `$("button").click(function(){.......}`  что бы он работал только один раз. Не понимаю что спросить у интернета.
  все целиком тут [github](https://github.com/KonstantinVolny/simoneGame)

```js
// Variabl List
var level = 2;
var tracNextLevelArray = [];
var ansverArray = [];
var count = 0;
var misakeNumber = 0;
var gameIsOn = 1;
var numbercOfLeftButtons = 0;

//funcion List

//enter in Game

function main() {
  // refreshAllSkrioInfo();
  if (gameIsOn == 1) {
    console.log("функция майн запущена");
    gameIsOn = 0;
    count = 0;
    misakeNumber = 0;
    ansverArray = [];
    refreshAllSkrioInfo();

    tracGenerator();
    showTrac();
    chekAll();
    goLevel();
    chekAll();

  } else {
    console.log("отмена повторного запуска");
  }
  return 0;
}


$("button").click(main);

// trackGnenerator

function tracGenerator() {
  tracNextLevelArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {

    var randomNumber1_4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    tracNextLevelArray.push(randomNumber1_4);

  }
  console.log(tracNextLevelArray);
  // console.log( "длинна" + tracNextLevelArray.length);
  // console.log("level " + level);
}

//function sleep

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// function pressBTN

function pressButI(qq) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(`.button_${qq}`).toggleClass("pushButton");
  }, 300);

  $(`.button_${qq}`).toggleClass("pushButton");
}

//shouTrac

async function showTrac() {

  for (var i = 0; i < tracNextLevelArray.length; i++) {

    if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 1) {

      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);


    } else if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 2) {
      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);



    } else if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 3) {
      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);
      // alert("это 3");

    } else if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 4) {
      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);

    }

  }

}

function goLevel() {
  //    $("button").click(chekAll());
  // console.log(" goLevel is activ")
  $("button").click(function() {
    var numberOfButten = $(event.target).text();
    console.log("приняли значение с кнопки " + numberOfButten);
    console.log("щелчок номер" + count);
    if (numberOfButten == tracNextLevelArray[count]) {
      console.log("сравнили значение  " + numberOfButten + " с итым эл. массива " + tracNextLevelArray[count])
      ansverArray.push(numberOfButten);
      console.log("добавили в массив  " + ansverArray);
      count = count + 1;
      numbercOfLeftButtons = level - ansverArray.length;
      refreshAllSkrioInfo();
      if (ansverArray.length == tracNextLevelArray.length) {
        level++;
        gameIsOn = 1;
        ansverArray = [];
        count = 0;
        refreshAllSkrioInfo();
        console.log("Next level is " + level + " . Click any button to start.");
        return 0;
      }
      numbercOfLeftButtons = tracNextLevelArray.length - ansverArray.length;
      refreshAllSkrioInfo();
    } else {

      // misakeNumber++;
      $("body").addClass("errorClass");
      // console.log("ошибка");
      //await sleep(200);
      $("body").removeClass("errorClass");
      refreshAllSkrioInfo();
    }

    return 0;

  });

  return 0;
}

// function addInformationInHTML (information,adressHTML)


// addInformationInHTML("levelNumberClass", levelNunber, Level number = );

function refreshAllSkrioInfo() {
  $(".levelNumberClass").text("Yore level is " + level);
  $(".mistakeNumberClass").text(" You have " + misakeNumber + " mistake");
  $(".numbercOfLeftButtonsClass").text("Left  " + numbercOfLeftButtons + " buttons");
}


function clean() {
  var tracNextLevelArray = [];
  var ansverArray = [];
  var count = 0;
  var misakeNumber = 0;
  console.log("очистка произошла");
}


function chekAll() {
  console.log("count = " + count);
  console.log("ansverArray = " + ansverArray);
  console.log("tracNextLevelArray" + tracNextLevelArray);
  console.log("level = " + level);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #110d40;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-family: fantasy;
  color: #5fe3d1;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%
}

.allButton {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttonSise {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px, 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: black;
}

.allButton {
  margin-top: 1%;
}


/* BUTTEN */

.pushButton {
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 2);
  opacity: .3;
}

.button_1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.button_2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.button_3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button_4 {
  background-color: Blue;
}


/* class erore */

.errorClass {
  background-color: red;
}

.informClass {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.informDiv {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.win {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon_Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Simon Game </h1>
  <div class="informDiv">
    <h2 class=" informClass levelNumberClass">Press any key </h2>
    <h2 class=" informClass mistakeNumberClass">Press any key </h2>
    <h2 class=" informClass numbercOfLeftButtonsClass"> Press any key</h2>
  </div>


  <div class="allButton">
    <div class="firsSlayd">
      <button class="buttonSise button_1" type="button" name="button">1</button>
      <button class="buttonSise button_2 " type="button" name="button">2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="secondSlayd">
      <button class="buttonSise button_3" type="button" name="button">3</button>
      <button class="buttonSise button_4" type="button" name="button">4</button>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

В функции `goLevel()`, которую вы вызываете каждый раз при вызове функции  `main` навешиваются обработчики на те же кнопки. В JS на одном и том же элементе может быть сколько угодно обработчиков событий.

Если вам надо вызывать функцию `goLevel` при клике, уберите установку обработчика события и вызывайте тело функции напрямую.

```js
// Variabl List
var level = 2;
var tracNextLevelArray = [];
var ansverArray = [];
var count = 0;
var misakeNumber = 0;
var gameIsOn = 1;
var numbercOfLeftButtons = 0;

//funcion List

//enter in Game

function main() {
  // refreshAllSkrioInfo();
  if (gameIsOn == 1) {
    console.log("функция майн запущена");
    gameIsOn = 0;
    count = 0;
    misakeNumber = 0;
    ansverArray = [];
    refreshAllSkrioInfo();

    tracGenerator();
    showTrac();
    chekAll();
    goLevel();
    chekAll();

  } else {
    console.log("отмена повторного запуска");
  }
  return 0;
}


$("button").click(main);

// trackGnenerator

function tracGenerator() {
  tracNextLevelArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {

    var randomNumber1_4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    tracNextLevelArray.push(randomNumber1_4);

  }
  console.log(tracNextLevelArray);
  // console.log( "длинна" + tracNextLevelArray.length);
  // console.log("level " + level);
}

//function sleep

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// function pressBTN

function pressButI(qq) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(`.button_${qq}`).toggleClass("pushButton");
  }, 300);

  $(`.button_${qq}`).toggleClass("pushButton");
}

//shouTrac

async function showTrac() {

  for (var i = 0; i < tracNextLevelArray.length; i++) {

    if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 1) {

      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);


    } else if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 2) {
      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);



    } else if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 3) {
      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);
      // alert("это 3");

    } else if (tracNextLevelArray[i] == 4) {
      pressButI(tracNextLevelArray[i]);

      await sleep(1000);

    }

  }

}

function goLevel() {
    var numberOfButten = $(event.target).text();
    console.log("приняли значение с кнопки " + numberOfButten);
    console.log("щелчок номер" + count);
    if (numberOfButten == tracNextLevelArray[count]) {
      console.log("сравнили значение  " + numberOfButten + " с итым эл. массива " + tracNextLevelArray[count])
      ansverArray.push(numberOfButten);
      console.log("добавили в массив  " + ansverArray);
      count = count + 1;
      numbercOfLeftButtons = level - ansverArray.length;
      refreshAllSkrioInfo();
      if (ansverArray.length == tracNextLevelArray.length) {
        level++;
        gameIsOn = 1;
        ansverArray = [];
        count = 0;
        refreshAllSkrioInfo();
        console.log("Next level is " + level + " . Click any button to start.");
        return 0;
      }
      numbercOfLeftButtons = tracNextLevelArray.length - ansverArray.length;
      refreshAllSkrioInfo();
    } else {

      // misakeNumber++;
      $("body").addClass("errorClass");
      // console.log("ошибка");
      //await sleep(200);
      $("body").removeClass("errorClass");
      refreshAllSkrioInfo();
    }

  return 0;
}

// function addInformationInHTML (information,adressHTML)


// addInformationInHTML("levelNumberClass", levelNunber, Level number = );

function refreshAllSkrioInfo() {
  $(".levelNumberClass").text("Yore level is " + level);
  $(".mistakeNumberClass").text(" You have " + misakeNumber + " mistake");
  $(".numbercOfLeftButtonsClass").text("Left  " + numbercOfLeftButtons + " buttons");
}


function clean() {
  var tracNextLevelArray = [];
  var ansverArray = [];
  var count = 0;
  var misakeNumber = 0;
  console.log("очистка произошла");
}


function chekAll() {
  console.log("count = " + count);
  console.log("ansverArray = " + ansverArray);
  console.log("tracNextLevelArray" + tracNextLevelArray);
  console.log("level = " + level);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #110d40;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-family: fantasy;
  color: #5fe3d1;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%
}

.allButton {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttonSise {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px, 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: black;
}

.allButton {
  margin-top: 1%;
}


/* BUTTEN */

.pushButton {
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 2);
  opacity: .3;
}

.button_1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.button_2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.button_3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button_4 {
  background-color: Blue;
}


/* class erore */

.errorClass {
  background-color: red;
}

.informClass {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.informDiv {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.win {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon_Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Simon Game </h1>
  <div class="informDiv">
    <h2 class=" informClass levelNumberClass">Press any key </h2>
    <h2 class=" informClass mistakeNumberClass">Press any key </h2>
    <h2 class=" informClass numbercOfLeftButtonsClass"> Press any key</h2>
  </div>


  <div class="allButton">
    <div class="firsSlayd">
      <button class="buttonSise button_1" type="button" name="button">1</button>
      <button class="buttonSise button_2 " type="button" name="button">2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="secondSlayd">
      <button class="buttonSise button_3" type="button" name="button">3</button>
      <button class="buttonSise button_4" type="button" name="button">4</button>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз, когда выполняется функция `goLevel`, она добавляет новый обработчик события `click` элементам `button`.